# Как заставить min-height работать с процентами?

Tags: css

у меня есть вот такой код
упрощена версия

```css
.test1 {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.test2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80%;
}

.test3 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

.test4 {
  float: left;
  width: 400px;
  height: 1000px;
}

@media (max-width: 200px) {
  .test1 {
    min-height: 100px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="test1">
  <div class="test2">
    <div class="test4"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="test3">
  </div>
</div>
```

Я пытаюсь сделать так что бы test1 не уменьшался до определенного значения. В случае если test4 отсутствует 
Если экран меньше 200px и test4 отсутствует то test1 уменьшается до 100px а вместе с ним уменьшается test2 и test3 в процентном соотношение.
Если test4 присутствует то test3 должен быть размера 1000px.

Полная версия кода
[code](https://codepen.io/zeni-agentt/pen/pGMPWp)

Comment: % работают от родителя, если нужно от окна используйте viewport (vh или hw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример, используя ваш код, тут два варианта с test4 и без. Данный код работает если он лежит в корне сайта и нет родителя с размерами

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.test1 {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: skyblue;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.test2 {
  flex: 1 0 100px;
}

.test3 {
  flex: 1 0 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.test4 {
  width: 400px;
  height: 700px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

@media (max-width: 200px) {
  .test1 {
    min-height: 100px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="test1">
  <div class="test2">
    без test4
  </div>
  <div class="test3">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="test1">
  <div class="test2">
    <div class="test4">test4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="test3">
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

body{
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

body>div, .main>div{
  background-color: skyblue;
  flex-basis: 50px;
  border: 1px solid white;
}

.main{
  flex: 1 1 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.main .main__asside{
  background-color: yellow;
}

.main .main__content{
  background-color: lightgreen;
  flex: 1 1 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.main .main__content>div{
  background-color: orange;
  flex: 1 0 100px;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="main">
  <div class="main__asside"></div>
  <div class="main__content">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

Comment: Ответ хороший только вот test3 полностью пропал.

Comment: Я не проверял, у вас flex + width 100% каким он должен быть по идеи?

Comment: Полная версия кода  https://codepen.io/zeni-agentt/pen/pGMPWp . В идеале Надо что бы черный футер находился на дне салатового дива а оранжевый и зеленый должны покрывать это расстояние. Я стараюсь сделать так что бы только оранжевый див менял свой размер в зависимости от размера экрана. и количества розовых дивов.

Comment: Добавил свой вариант